# How to block specific YouTube videos

Tags: youtube

I want to block specify videos on YouTube.
To be clear, I do **not** want to block:

- The whole channel
- Some keywords
- Video recommendations

I just want to block a specific video given its URL and I want youtube to remember these *blacklisted* videos in my account so that whenever I use the youtube app or the browser, as long as I am logged in I do not see these videos anywhere on youtube. Is that feasible?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible through YouTube itself and as such it is not possible to store the list of blocked videos directly in your YouTube account.

However, as @user0 also mentions, there are other solutions such as browser extensions that will hide them for you. E.g., [BlockTube](https://github.com/amitbl/blocktube) (available for Firefox and Chromium‐based browsers) allows you to “Block videos via: […] Video ID” which is what you’d want. Depending on the specific browser and browser extension it may be possible to synchronise your blocklist in the browser’s “sync” solution (e.g., Firefox Sync or Google Chrome Sync) or in some other manner.

Answer (score -1):

### option 1:

- use hosts file
- go to  **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\**
- right click on **HOSTS**
- open it with Notepad
- add new line: **`127.0.0.1 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5qhNRmMilI`**
- save changes

  [image]

### _______________________________________________________________

### option 2:

- use an extension of your choice: **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/block%20url?_category=extensions)**

Comment: Does the hosts thing actually work? It won't block YouTube from recommending it on other pages (a pretty big downside) and there are so many other formats for YT URLs that you might have to block it several times until the block actually sticks.